# WPF Tree Parent Child Insertion:

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am trying to create Below parent child structur using WPF tree.

```
Tree

 ->Parent

    ->Child

      ->Grand Child.
```

I have written the below code which is not able to insert for child. Please help me to fix this.

```
<Window x:Class="NewTree_DynamicNode.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="treeFileSystem" TreeViewItem.Expanded="treeFileSystem_Expanded_1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Categories" x:Name="_ImageTree" Tag="hi" 
                  x:FieldModifier="private">
                <TreeViewItem TextBlock.FontStyle="Italic" 
                    Header="Loading..." Name="treeFileSystem2"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>




private void treeFileSystem_Expanded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._ImageTree = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
            this._ImageTree.Items.Clear();

            try
            {
                for(int i=0 ; i<2; i++)  
                {
                   TreeViewItem temp = new TreeViewItem();
                   TreeViewItem temp1 = new TreeViewItem();
                    temp.Header = "Parent";
                    temp1.Header = "Child";
                    temp.Items.Add(temp1);                
                    this._ImageTree.Items.Add(temp);                      
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                  /////
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that every time you expand a node, the child node for the node you expand is always '`Parent`'

Im not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but heres some code:

```
TreeViewItem temp = new TreeViewItem();
temp.Header = "Child";
temp.Items.Add(null);
this._ImageTree.Items.Add(temp);
```

**EDIT** - this is for specific names in hierarchy

```
TreeViewItem temp = new TreeViewItem();
var header = string.Empty;
switch (_ImageTree.Header.ToString())
{
    case "Categories":
        header = "Parent";
        break;
    case "Parent":
        header = "Child";
        break;
    case "Child":
        header = "GrandChild";
        break;
    default:
        header = "Child of " + _ImageTree.Header;
        break;
}
temp.Header = header;
temp.Items.Add(null);
this._ImageTree.Items.Add(temp);
```

Comment: Hi dean: When I click on my Tree it should open with Parent and when I click on Parent it should open with child and so on....  I want below tree structure                                             Tree                                                                                    --->Parent                                                                              ---->Child                                                                      ----->GrandChild

Comment: added logic for setting header